# Objective-C: Get @param from within BOOLEAN declaration?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get a parameter to return from a (BOOL) declaration, but I am hitting a wall understanding what is happening here.

I'm working with an SDK that has this in their DTDevices.h:

```
/**
 @param current stores the charge current in mA (normally it is 500) upon return.
 @param error pointer to NSError object, where error information is stored in case function fails. You can pass nil if you don't want that information
 @return TRUE if function succeeded, FALSE otherwise
 */
-(BOOL)getUSBChargeCurrent:(int *)current error:(NSError **)error;
```

This seems to work to get a return of the BOOLEAN:

```
if ([dtdev getUSBChargeCurrent:true error:&error]) { }
```

But no amount of trial and error will return me the value of getUSBChargeCurrent:current

I'll also point out that this is another declared method:

```
-(BOOL)setUSBChargeCurrent:(int)current error:(NSError **)error;
```

I don't seem to have this problem with -(void) functions, so I am wondering what the correct way to do this is and why I have created this wall of understanding for myself.

Comment: The function only returns a YES or NO. I'm not sure what you're wanting to be returned. Also, you need to be passing an int value as a parameter and not a `true`. You can see from the method declaration that "(normally it is 500)".

Comment: The method name is `setUSBChargeCurrent`, notice the "set". That indicates th methods sets something, not gets it. A method to get the current would probably look like: '- (int)USBChargeCurrent;`

Comment: There is both a setter and a getter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, you should pass a pointer to an int value, which then will be set to the charge current.

```
int current;
if ([dtdev getUSBChargeCurrent:&current error:&error]) {
    //current is now set the the USBChargeCurrent you wanted to have
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No amount of trial and error will the method **ever** return a value other than a `BOOL` value. That's the method declaration.

Look at the description of the method, it explains the return type as

> TRUE if function succeeded, FALSE otherwise.

`-(void)` functions don't return anything, as they are `void`.

Comment: Right, but it was how to tap into the param that I didn't get...I'm about to answer this because I figured it out.